# recurse through powershell object

Tags: powershell

i am trying to browse through result i received from a command, Problem is when i access property i get only property name not corresponding path.

[image]

> $com1 = Get-ChildItem
>   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall*' | ? { $_
>   -match "Firefox" }
>
> ```
> Command i tried to recurse:
> $prop = $com1 | Select-Object  'Property' # Select only item property
> ```

then i get result without any mapping of property values.

**result i get pasted below**

```
Property                                        
--------                                               
{Comments, DisplayIcon, DisplayName, DisplayVersion...}
```

i expect to get value of comments and displayicon as i get in the image in the first time.

Comment: Please show the full code (ie. how is `$com1` assigned in the first place)

Comment: $com1  = Get-ChildItem 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | ? { $_ -match "Firefox" } i am checking from installed apps.

Comment: Please avoid adding information in the comments. Please edit your question instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) to get the actual property values from registry keys:

```
$PropertyValue = ($com1 | Get-ItemProperty -Name "property").property
```

Comment: thankyou actually worked with this modification ..  ($com1 | Get-ItemProperty) above command gives me error as "Get-ItemProperty : Property property does not exist at path"

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51809888/45375):

In **PSv5+** you can use the [`Get-ItemPropertyValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itempropertyvalue) cmdlet, which simplifies matters by retrieving the data (property value) directly:

```
$PropertyValue = $com1 | Get-ItemPropertyValue -Name Property
```

**Alternatively**, given that `$com1` appears to have been retrieved with [`Get-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-item) from a [registry-provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/registry-provider) location and is therefore an instance of type [`[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey), you can call its [`.GetValue()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey.getvalue) directly:

```
$com1.GetValue('Property')
```